# How to access Iphone camera using MATLAB Mobile

Tags: iphone, ios, matlab, android-camera, ip-camera

I have been searching for how to access the iphone camera using MATLAB and I have found it can be accessed by app called IP CAM with the use of a local network. Yet the solution of IP Cam program existed on apple store isn't working so well for my application because I'm trying to build a real time image capturing program using Iphone's camera and Matlab mobile with later processing (and this method keeps MATLAB busy as long as it display the scene and I still want MATLAB to run in the foreground instead of IP Cam).

So far I've downloaded MATLAB Mobile and the connector and connected the Iphone to MATLAB on my laptop, so is there any one who knows how to access the Iphone's camera on MATLAB Mobile and capture the image so that it can be stored on MATLAB workspace for later processing ? or is there any one who can suggest tutorials any piece of material helping me through this.I'd appreciate your answer very much and thank you in advance.

P.S: if there is a solution on android's devices it's also work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of iPhone based solutions but here is an opportunity for android based system. I will suggest you to used [Sensor EX](https://sites.google.com/site/tarsensorics/). I have used it for sometime to acquire Accelerometer, Gyroscope data set along with live images. This tool has bindings available for MATLAB beside other programming environments. Feel free to ask questions if you cannot figure out that how this system works.